# AWS - Confirm User Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to register a user in a **Cognito UserPool** but I'm having issue with the [Pre-signup trigger](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-pre-signup).
I've configured a lambda like in the [docs example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#aws-lambda-triggers-pre-registration-example)

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    event.response.autoConfirmUser=true;
    callback(null, event);
};
```

Using CloudWatch logs I can see that the `autoConfirmUser` attribute is correctly set to true, but the user isn't confirmed.
Here is the account in the UserPool:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling

```
context.done(error, event);
```

like in the examples provided?

Comment: I've tried using this but it doesn't confirm the user